# Moderator blog 'view all posts' link is 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found

On the [Stack Exchange Community Moderator Blog](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/), there is a link in the sidebar under the Latest Articles section to view all posts.

> [image]

This link goes to **http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/archive/** which is a 404.